# Is there a way to only show Custom Meta Data on single posts from certain catagories

Tags: categories, post-meta

I am trying to use this code to display something in the 'single.php' file on the theme when the post is of a certian catagory.

```
$cat = get_query_var('cat');
if ($cat == '4') {
echo "post";
} else {
echo "no data";
}
```

But it seems to ignore the $cat var query and as such on every post display the no data message.

The cat var is not in the url.

Answer (score 2):

`get_query_var('cat');`  only returns the category id in a category archive page;

in a single post, try to use, for instance:

`wp_get_post_categories()`

example:

`if( in_array(4, wp_get_post_categories($post->ID)) ) :`

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_post_categories

Comment: That works a treat.